# php load big json file once

Tags: php, json

I created a local web application to display and interact with data that I got an a big Json file (around 250 Mo). I have several function in order to display differently the data but currently each one starts by reading and parsing the Json file :

```
$string = file_get_contents("myFile.json");
$json_a = json_decode($string, true);
```

The thing is that it is quite slow (about 4 seconds) because the file is big... So I would like to parse the Json file once and for all and store the parsed data in memory so that each function could use it :

```
session_start();
$string = file_get_contents("myFile.json");
$_SESSION['json_a'] = json_decode($string, true);
```

and then use `$_SESSION['json_a']` in my functions.
But I got an error when the function access to this `$_SESSION['json_a']` variable :

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 195799278 bytes)
```

I assume it is because the file is too big.. but why does it crash when the variable is used and not when it is built ? And why can I do it with my first solution (parsing each time) if it is too big for the memory ?

And finally my real question : how can I optimise that ? (I know sql database would be much better but I happen to have json data)

Comment: You'll likely need a streaming parser. https://github.com/salsify/jsonstreamingparser

Comment: There might be a way to load this data using smaller chunks but im not sure how you would do this. Personally I would look at the file and see if there is anyway I could break it down into smaller pieces. Also I would not load it into a session, sessions were never meant to hold so much data. Once you have borken the data into smaller pieces I would look at using APC or memcache since that will be much better for holding this type of data

Comment: You could also just open the file and seek to the needed position instead of reading it all into memory.

Comment: Sessions are serialized when saved, creating the same problem that you have now. It is also an awful lot to save. You should parse it and then put it in a database (temporary table if only used once).

Comment: you're ending up with about 3 copies of the data in memory: the raw json version, the decoded version created/returned from json_decode, and the copy you're trying to stuff into $_SESSION.